# XSLT character-map only to text (not to attr values)

Tags: xslt

How to prevent character-map getting applied to the attr values. Want to make it to apply only to text nodes?

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:character-map name="char-map">
  <xsl:output-character character="-" string="-&#x200b;"/>
</xsl:character-map>

<xsl:output method="xhtml" use-character-maps="char-map"/>
```

And I get the below output, where the mapping is applied for both attr and text node:

```
<!-- Have to stop chat mapping on attr:id value -->
<span class="author" id="c-&#8203;001"> //should be id="c-001
   text-&#x8203;text
</span>
```

[w3.org:](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-character-map) A character map allows a specific character appearing in a text or attribute node in the final result tree to be substituted by a specified string of characters during serialization.

Is there any workaround for this scenario? any suggestion too would help?

Comment: Well, there is the XPath `replace` function you could use in templates matching `text()` nodes, in particular if you just need that `replace(., '-', '-&#x200b;')` replacement.

Comment: Yes, got it, thanks